# Jenkins Workflow Plugin Link to Downstream Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I've just started working with the Workflow plugin.

The set-up I have currently consists of a Workflow script that uses the build step to basically define a pipeline made up of multiple downstream jobs.

This is working well but their there isn't really any link between the output of Workflow build and the output from all the downstream builds, is their a way to either,

- Link from the Workflow project build output to all the corresponding downstream builds.
- Capture the console output of the downstream jobs and include it in the output of the Workflow job.

I'm hoping with either of these options it will be possible to see the output from the whole pipeline via the Workflow job output.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the intention of Workflow is to replace pipelines of various Jenkins jobs with just a single job. This may be why Workflow doesn't make any significant effort to link to downstream jobs. I've been converting my "pipelines" to monolithic Workflow jobs, and really appreciating the fact that all the actions are more tightly grouped together.

Comment: The main reason were using a pipeline approach is for re-use between different pipelines that need to perform similar tasks. I guess some of this will depend on the answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083616/jenkins-workflow-plugin-using-a-groovy-library

Answer (score 0):

> Link from the Workflow project build output to all the corresponding downstream builds.

[PR 218](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/pull/218) under review as of this writing.

> Capture the console output of the downstream jobs and include it in the output of the Workflow job.

[JENKINS-26124](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26124)