# Jenkins Workflow Plugin Using a Groovy Library

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

As I'm writing more and more Groovy to use with the Jenkins Workflow plugin I've started getting to the point where I've got re-usable code that could be used in multiple scripts.

What would be the best way of sharing this code? Is it possible to produce my own .jar with the shared code in and utilize this from within the Workflow script? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually got this working in the end by using our own git repo but putting a symlink into workflow-libs/src to point at that repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Global Lib as pointed in other comments and/or use the `load` step to load you own scripts from somewhere (i.e. your SCM just checked out previously).

More info about `load`: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#triggering-manual-loading

Comment: load works much better for our needs as we can pull in our groovy source from any repo.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Workflow Global Library is for! https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/cps-global-lib/README.md  I use this in my installation, it's a great feature of Workflow. Right now I just have one "helper" class that contains methods common to all builds, but as other teams start to adopt Workflow they are showing interest in creating their own classes to use for subsets of our builds.

Comment: This look great, we already have our workflow scripts under source control in our own git repository that Jenkins pulls from. Is there anyway we can get Jenkins to source the global library from this repo rather than creating a new one internally?

Answer (score 0):

The [Workflow Remote File Loader plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin/) might meet your needs.